# MPEGTS h264 high@L4.0 can not play on ios device

Tags: ios, h.264, mpeg

My MPEG-TS video has problem playing on iOS via HTTP Live Streaming. The iPhone can play the file, but it seems it lost half of its frames. The video is slow and not continuous and smooth on the iPhone, but the VLC can play the stream without problems. I have posted the information of the mpegts file, it was encoded under profile High@L4.0 H264.  iPhone 5c or 5s should have the ability to handle it.

Information probed by mediainfo command:

```
General
ID                                       : 1 (0x1)
Complete name                            : segment00007.ts
Format                                   : MPEG-TS
File size                                : 169 KiB
Duration                                 : 5s 990ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 216 Kbps
Video
ID                                       : 65 (0x41)
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
Codec ID                                 : 27
Duration                                 : 6s 63ms
Bit rate                                 : 206 Kbps
Width                                    : 640 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Stream size                              : 152 KiB (90%)




$ avconv -i segment00007.ts 
avconv version 9.14-6:9.14-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Jul 15 2014 13:57:40 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
[mpegts @ 0x16e7840] Invalid timestamps stream=0, pts=327815314, dts=327815357, size=7191
[mpegts @ 0x16e7840] Invalid timestamps stream=0, pts=327997410, dts=327997563, size=7232
[mpegts @ 0x16e7840] Invalid timestamps stream=0, pts=328104538, dts=328104565, size=1458
[mpegts @ 0x16e7840] Invalid timestamps stream=0, pts=328117902, dts=328118015, size=1476
[mpegts @ 0x16e7840] Invalid timestamps stream=0, pts=328141590, dts=328141634, size=1573
[mpegts @ 0x16e7840] Invalid timestamps stream=0, pts=328165614, dts=328165629, size=1913
[mpegts @ 0x16e7840] Invalid timestamps stream=0, pts=328180354, dts=328180554, size=7192
[mpegts @ 0x16e7840] max_analyze_duration reached
Input #0, mpegts, from 'segment00007.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:06.08, start: 3642.385822, bitrate: 227 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0.0[0x41]: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 640x480, 30.08 fps, 90k tbn
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: Did you ensure you have a good bandwidth ? (i.e. issue is on iPhone, not on streaming)

Comment: @Coconop I tested it with iphone using the app VLC, and it works fine, so the bandwidth should not be the problem, the issue happens when tested it with safari of iphone.